# Can't define answers from textfield input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a text based adventure, and I want to get the user's input through a text field. Basically, it's all about hiding and showing DIVs.

Right now I'm trying to do something basic, such as choosing a character's gender.

So, in html, I wrote the question with a textfield and a button. Then you have all of the DIVs for the different answers.

```
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">
   <h1>Who are you</h1>
   <p>Tell us some things about you. Are you a <u>BOY</u> or a <u>GIRL</u> ?</p>
   <input id="t-dois" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('b-dois').click()"/>
   <a id="b-dois" onclick="buttonOne()" style="display: none;"></a>
</div>      
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">
   <div id="div4-1" style="display:none;">
      <h1>You're a Boy.</h1>
      <p></p>
   </div>
   <div id="div4-2" style="display:none;">
      <h1>You're a Girl.</h1>
      <p></p>
   </div>
   <div id="div4-3" style="display:none;">
      <h1>That's not a valid answer.</h1>
      <p>Answer again.</p>
      <input id="t-dois" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('b-dois').click()"/>
      <a id="b-dois" onclick="buttonOne()" style="display: none;"></a>
   </div>
```

So you basically type 'BOY' in the text field, and it runs the `ButtonOne()` function. This is the code I wrote for it:

```
function buttonOne() {
   var input = document.getElementById('t-dois');
   if (input === "BOY"){
      document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('div4-1').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('div4-3').style.display = "none";
   } else if (input === "GIRL") {
      document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('div4-2').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('div4-3').style.display = "none";
   } else {
       document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById('div4-3').style.display = "block";
   };
};
```

The function is not running properly.  It always ends up with the last `else`, which is the non valid answer, which makes me think the input is not being correctly processed. Could you help me or give me any tips?

Comment: `document.getElementById('t-dois').value`

Comment: input.value === "BOY"

Comment: Start using debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to display `div3` in the beginning, and based on the typed result want to display either `div4-1`, `div4-2` or `div4-3`.
Then you should have `div3` and `<a>` displayed in the beginning to start with something. You must have a text for `<a>Some Text</a>`, otherwise your anchor won't display anything to click on!

```
<div id="div3" style="display:block;">
    <h1>Who are you</h1>
    <p>Tell us some things about you. Are you a <u>BOY</u> or a <u>GIRL</u> ?</p>
    <input id="t-dois" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('b-dois').click()" />
    <a id="b-dois" onclick="buttonOne()" style="display: block;">Submit Answer!</a>
</div>
```

You didn't have a closing tag for `div4`, plus you shouldn't be using same Ids on multiple elements, in this case `t-dois` & `b-dois`. (You would be using more descriptive names though.)

```
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">
    <div id="div4-1" style="display:none;">
        <h1>You're a Boy.</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="div4-2" style="display:none;">
        <h1>You're a Girl.</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="div4-3" style="display:none;">
        <h1>That's not a valid answer.</h1>
        <p>Answer again.</p>
        <input id="t-dois2" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('b-dois').click()" />
        <a id="b-dois2" onclick="buttonOne()" style="display: none;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, you should be using `document.getElementById('t-dois').value` to get the entered text from the input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonOne() {
        var input = document.getElementById('t-dois').value;
        alert(input);
        if (input === "BOY") {
            document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('div4-1').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('div4-3').style.display = "none";
        } else if (input === "GIRL") {
            document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('div4-2').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('div4-3').style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('div4-3').style.display = "block";
        };

    };
</script>
```

If you convert the entered text to lower case (using `.toLowerCase()`) and compare to 'boy' and 'girl', all 'boy' & 'girl' strings with different cases would be covered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your input variable equal to ('t-dois').value, first. Then, I would call .toLowerCase() on input and compare it with (input === "boy"). That way, the user can enter Boy, BOY, bOy, or boy and they'll all work.